# Why is the dielectric constant of copper plate infinite?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, dielectric, metals

There was a question asking the electrostatic force between two charges if a a copper plate of thickness d/2 is kept between them. The effective force was 0. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copper is pretty good conductor of electricity,  but let us assume it is dielectric then

when a copper material is placed  in electric field $\vec E$, there would be induced charges on copper material which would cause the net electric field to get $0$ inside,so

at any point inside dielectric net electric field $\vec E_{net}$ $=$ $\cfrac {\vec E}{K}$, but inside conductor like copper net electric field is $0$ so $\vec E_{net} = 0$

so $K = \cfrac{\vec E}{0}$ hence $K = \infty$